# How to retrieve text content inside a table without any element id

Tags: javascript, html, events, html-table, click

I have a simple code of an html table. I need to write a Javascript function that is able to alert the content of any row that is selected using the mouse(by clicking).

I do not have any element id. So I need to use the event associated to the click of the mouse...

For example:

```
<tr>
  <td onclick="...">Mamata</td>
  <td>Sharma</td>
  <td>20</td>
</tr>
```

I need to write a javascript function that is able to display with an alert any content of the table I select with a click.
For example If I click on 'Mamata', I need to see an alert appearing on the screen displaying 'Mamata'.

Comment: put the onclick on the tr tag and get event.target.value in the script

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
  td[i].onclick = function() {
    alert(this.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Mamata</td>
    <td>Sharma</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Or the simple and short jQuery version:

`$("td").click(function() {
  alert(this.innerHTML);
})`

Comment: the comment is good. but answer uses global variable `i` and ridiculously repeated DOM calls

Comment: @Aprillion Right! Thx for hint. Changed it.

Comment: to spell out my second point: `var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");` before the for loop

Comment: @Aprillion I have changed it. Good optimization.

Answer (score 0):

define this function

function alertContent(sender) {alert(sender.innerHTML);}

and use it in

onclick="javascript:alertContent(this)"

Answer (score 0):

something like this,

```
<tr>
  <td onClick="alert(this.innerHTML)">Mamata</td>
  <td>Sharma</td>
  <td>20</td>
</tr>
```

a better option is the following:
declare a function,

```
function alertcontent()
    {
        _sender = arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0].target;
        if (_sender.tagName == "TD")
        {
            alert(_sender.innerHTML);
        }
    }
```

and assign this to the tables onclick event, like;

```
<table onclick="alertcontent()">
...
...
</table>
```

this way u can use less coding...

Comment: how is using a deprecated API "a better option" plz? [arguments.callee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee)

Comment: also `_sender` is a global variable

Comment: in case every cell/multiple cells should be alerted, what is better to do ? write for every cell 'onclick=""' ? or use the function assigning on tables onclick event?

Are u sure _sender is a global variable ?

Comment: about using deprecated api, in my previous comment, did not understand clearly. you might be right about that. 
my idea was avoiding to write a event handler for every cell that needs to be alerted.

Comment: just `"use strict";`, copy paste to any statically checking IDE, and/or run through a linter and see for yourself...

Comment: I have een reading about arguments.callee following the link you provided. Did not know about that. It was a good crossbrowser working solution.  I have been searching for replacement for this. I think I will have to pass "event" as parameter to get it working also in Firefox. IE and Chrome supports window.event what FF does not.
But about "_sender" variable I have used, I am not sure if it is a global variable...
BTW +1 for providing info about the api, thanks.

Comment: `var _sender = ...;` also starting `{` at the end of a line is preferable from new line, to make it easier to avoid the `return \n {}` ASI tarpit

Comment: first it is user specific, second it was a copy paste issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution - http://jsbin.com/wigolunowa/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td onClick="alert(this.innerHTML)">Mamata</td>
      <td>Sharma</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just try adding an "OnClick" event to every single `<td>` with an alert to its innerHTML, something like this:

```
<td onclick="alert('Your value is '+this.innerHTML)">1</td>
<td onclick="alert('Your value is '+this.innerHTML)">ABC</td>
```

Or you can create JS function that loops through all the `<td>` cells (you select them by tag) and get their values:

```
var myCell = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

for(var i=0; i<=myCell.length; i++){
    myCell[i].addEventListener('click', valueOnClick);
}

function valueOnClick(){
    alert('Your value is '+this.textContent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click handler to the table (once) and check which cell was clicked. The following example checks for cells (with "TD" tags) but can easily be changed to check for rows:

javascript

```
function showElementContent(event, table)
{
    event = event || window.event;
    for(var node = event.target || event.srcElement; node && node!= table; node = node.parentNode)
    {   if(node.tagName == "TD")
            break;
    }
     alert(node.innerText);
}
```

html

```
<table onclick="showElementContent(event, this)">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>a cell</td>
      <td>a cell with a <span>spanned element</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably way too late to help but it's an approach not suggested by others and might be of use to someone else. At the very least it's an interesting way of using the DOM and "this" keyword to identify elements by relative positioning and not using an explicit element id.

Making a slight change to the HTML, use keyword "this" as an argument for your JavaScript function.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td onclick="myfunc(this)">Mamata</td>
        <td>Sharma</td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The JavaScript function then takes advantage of the parent element/node to get the `<tr>` that the `<td>` resides within. Once we have the row we can get the number of cells and loop over each `<td>` element within the `<tr>` and get the text content within.

In the example below I'm assuming that the format for the alert message should just be a string of all the `<td>` elements on a row, but this would also be trivial to modify for a JSON or other format of output.

```js
function myfunc(td_ele){
            var td_row = td_ele.parentNode; //From button_ele get it's parentNode e.g. the <tr> element
            var alert_msg = "";
            //Iterate  over the rows cell length
            for(i=0; i<td_row.cells.length; i++){
                alert_msg += td_row.cells[i].firstChild.textContent + " "; //stitch together alert_msg taking each rows cell child elements text
            }

            alert(alert_msg);
        }
```